# Laravel store Multiple input value for each item

Tags: php, database, laravel, collections, eloquent

I want to store each member's shopping day using a laravel collection, but it doesn't show me each member's data, it only shows one user's data:

[image]

[image]

**Blade template:**

```
@foreach($members as $member)
      <div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">{{$member->name}}</label>
          <div class="col-sm-8">
              <select style="background-color: #e6e9f1" class="js-select2 form-control" name="day[{{$member->id}}][]" style="width: 100%;" data-placeholder="Choose single or multiple day" multiple="">
                  <option></option>
                  @foreach($days as $day)
                      <option value="{{$day->name}}">{{$day->name}}</option>
                  @endforeach
              </select>
          </div>
      </div>
@endforeach
```

**Controller:**

```
public function assign(Request $request)
{
    $collections = collect($request->day);
    foreach ($collections as $collection){
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the field name for the `test fields`

Comment: `member_id` and  `day_id`

Answer (score -1):

Here $collections get both two users data. But when 1st iteration in loop it returned that user's (first user) data and next iteration will never happen as function has already returned data. You can Just return the $collections variable. You will find all there.

Comment: Then it return like this `{"1":["Friday","Satday","Sunday"],"20":["Satday","Sunday"]}` but how can i catch every item

Comment: dd($collection); also return same

Comment: That means data has been passed. Now use below:-
foreach($collections as $memid=> $collection)
{
         // build insert query from here
 }

Comment: Post you db structure here. Using model this type of insertion may take huge times.

Comment: `Schema::create('member_shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('member_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('member_id')->references('id')
                ->on('members')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('day_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('day_id')->references('id')
                ->on('day_shops')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });`